# Path to my .html file NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, hapi.js

I'm trying to host my web page locally using [Static file server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inert#static-file-server).

I have a file located in a folder on my Desktop, named `index.js`, that is going to run this server information.

my code is:

```
const Path = require('path');
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Inert = require('inert');

const server = new Hapi.Server({
    connections: {
        routes: {
            files: {
                relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'public')
            }
        }
    }
});
server.connection({ port: 3000 });

server.register(Inert, () => {});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
        directory: {
            path: './knox/index.html',
            redirectToSlash: true,
            index: true
        }
    }
});

server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

if you look at the link, I've tried filling in things that will open my `index.html` file from that code. I'm not sure if I'm pathing to my `index.html` file correctly. My file is located at `desktop/knox(folder name)/index.html`, along with all my other files.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand the file structure based on your question. Assuming your file structure is :

```
    |-Desktop
    |---index.js
    |---knox
    |---|---index.html
```

`relativeTo` : Gives the base position of the file we will choose in `handler`.

Change
`relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, './knox')` and

```
    handler: {
      directory: {
        path: './index.html',
        redirectToSlash: true,
        index: true
      }
   }
```